# How to threshold a grayscale image with lighting and noise

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, adaptive-threshold, image-thresholding

I am trying to threshold images with challenging noise.

[image: Image example].

The numbers on the side are the dimensions. I have tried various standard methods:

```
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,95,255,0) 
#cv2.THRESH_BINARY

thresh2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,7,0.5)
thresh3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,3,1.5)


# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3),0)
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

I want to segment the "lighter" portion inside the darker grey zone (or vice versa). I have played with various kernel sizes, and constant values but nothing is giving me a good segmentation. Any ideas what else i can try or how to improve the results? Some sample results i get using the code is [image: here]

Comment: Global thresholding looks promising. You coud dilate the result, eventually perform an operation of closing.

Comment: Try histogram equalization. It might work